# Elasticsearch NEST return matched field

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using Elasticsearch with the NEST .NET client to perform full-text search. I have looked around the internet to see if there is a way to accomplish what I want to do. I want to know if there is a way to get the fieldname that matched a search string and the count of documents that matched on that field.

I have an object that tooks like

```
class Person{
  public string FirstName {get;set;}
  public string Surname {get;set;}
  public string StreetName {get;set;}
 ......
}
```

so a full-text search for "Parker" could match on any of these field so I want to return something that would look like the json below:

```
response: {[
  {
    MatchOn: "FirstName",  
    Records: [
      {
         FirstName: "Parker",
         Surname: "Thomas",
         StreetName: "Main"
      },
      {
         FirstName: "Parker",
         Surname: "Smith",
         StreetName: "JFK"
      }
      .....
    ]
  }
]}
```

Comment: Which field or fields are you searching against, and how are you performing that search?

Comment: You specify which fields you want to search on right... so you already have the data....

Comment: @Callum I'm doing full-text search specifying '_all'

Comment: You can get information for how a score is calculated for a given document by adding `.Explain()` to the NEST call. This will provide an explanation for how the score has been calculated by Lucene. Be aware that this can be a relatively expensive operation to perform and will make the response size much bigger. Often however, using the `_score` from the hits metadata is sufficient in many cases, but if you want the breakdown, then explain will provide it -https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-explain.html

Comment: In addition, if you're targeting the `_all` field, I don't believe a reference to the original field from which values have been pulled is preserved. Worth checking